# How to open an image on remote computer via SSH? (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, python, images

I am looking for a way to display an Image Remotely

For example, 
1. user foo is viewing Ubuntu 16.04 computer via monitor 
2. I am connected through SSH to user's foo computer
3. I want to display an Image so user foo will see it

How can I accomplish this? 
If I use the command "display", it shows the image, but only if I run it directly from the same computer 
If I run it through SSH, it is not shown :(

Comment: Did You set the DISPLAY variable in the SSH session to point to local Display of computer? (`DISPLAY=:0 display update_system_soon.png`)? You also may need some permissions to use another users/sessions display.. (so ensure XAUTHORITY is set to Target users xauth file or You imported the credentials in Yours.)  what is the error message You get when trying to display image?

Comment: The DISPLAY=:0 did the trick ! Thank you :) :)